# Xcode custom symbol image set asset

Tags: xcode, assets

From Apples [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/providing_images_for_different_appearances?language=objc) I read:

> An alternative to creating bitmap images is to use template images or symbol images instead. Template images specify the shape you want to draw, but not the associated color information. **Symbol images are similar to template images but are vector based, so they scale to different sizes.** Both types of images simplify the process for supporting Dark Mode. They also reduce the number of image assets you must ship with your app.

Do I understand this correct that I **can not** use a vector based `symbol image set` as a replacement for bitmap but scalable?

**Update**

My situation:
I've an Image Set in my iOS project. There I can add three bitmaps for the three scaling options iOS devices support. Those images must be of type *.png

Now I would like to replace those three bitmaps with a single vector graphic file *.svg. This seems not possible. If I want to use vector graphic images I've to add another asset type called "symbol image set" (Xcode -> Editor -> Add Assets -> New Symbol Image Set).

So far so good **but** now my question. Those "symbol image set" assets only the the shape but not the color information into account. That's why I would like the "old" way where the color information is taken into account but the file being a vector graphics file (*.svg).

Comment: Your statement is quite confusing. Can you provide a concrete example? From what I understand, Symbol Images (SFSymbols being the only system set right now) are 'glorified' fonts facilitated by the `UI/NS`Image apis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need a Symbol Set for what you are trying to achieve.

All you need is a vector image in `pdf` format, marking it as `Single Scale`

Then, you can mark the asset as `template` (meaning you can tint it with any color) or `original` if you want to retain its original colors.

Finally, note that although you supply vector images, Xcode by default will produce `png` versions for all scales behind the scenes. If you need to preserve the vector data (which can help in some cases where you need to upscale) you can enable `Preserve Vector Data` as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see. Is there an intended way to create such a pdf out of a scalable vector graphics (*.svg) file?

Comment: Sure, just export it as a pdf in any vector editor supporting the option. Note that the natural size of the vector (what you get as for its size when zoomed 100% in the vector document) will be the size of the image as seen by Xcode.